# C# Cannot redirect "git" process to standard output

Tags: c#, git, redirect, output

I'm quite newbie in C#. I'm trying to call a "subprocess" and retrieve its standard output. In the example above, I perform several tests. Some tests are done in VisualStudio (in "Debug" mode) and everything work as expected, no exception :)
    The final application is compiled then launched. And the problems arrive...

1. the 1st part, with ...Start(si) works fine
2. the 2nd part, with ...Start() show the terminal command and no text (OK), but I never retrieve any text from standard output/error (proc_output and proc_error are empty)
3. If I change the String cmd_arg... from "git" with "systeminfo", recompile and restart, this time the 2nd part works ! (proc_output contains lots of text)

So, as far I can understand, the 2nd part is OK for "systeminfo" but not for "git". I have observed that "git" starts a sub-process (thread), but I don't know if this is the root cause.
  I would greatly appreciated any help :) TIA

Code

```
//==============================================================================================//
String cmd_exe = "cmd.exe";                                                                     //
String cmd_arg = String.Format("/c \"{0}\"", "systeminfo");                                     //
//==============================================================================================//
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo();                                //Always work, terminal window appears and text visible
si.FileName               = cmd_exe                       ;                                     //
si.Arguments              = cmd_arg                       ;                                     //
si.UseShellExecute        = false                         ;                                     //
si.WindowStyle            = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal     ;                                     //
si.WorkingDirectory       = Pack.SIM_DIR.Replace('/','\\');                                     //
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(si);                                                           //Standardoutput is sent to screen
//==============================================================================================//
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();                             //Work within VisualStudio, DOES NOT work when the C# application is called as "sub" process
proc.StartInfo                        = si                       ;                              //  Take exactly the same information as previous
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true                     ;                              //  Redirect output
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError  = true                     ;                              //  Redirect error
proc.OutputDataReceived              += new DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_OutputDataReceived);  //  
proc.ErrorDataReceived               += new DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_ErrorDataReceived);   //  
proc_output = ""; proc_output_empty = true;                                                     //
proc_error  = ""; proc_error_empty  = true;                                                     //
proc.Start();                                                                                   //VisualStudio=OK  MSim=KO
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();                                                                     // 
proc.BeginErrorReadLine();                                                                      //
proc.WaitForExit(10 * 1000);                                                                    // 
proc.Close();                                                                                   //
//==============================================================================================//
```

Comment: Can you please reformat your code so that it's readable?

Comment: This code seems to work just fine for me.  What do you mean by "DOES NOT work when the C# application is called as "sub" process".  What on earth is a sub process?

Comment: Also those beautiful stars are not idiomatic C#.  Please don't do that.

Comment: The final application (the exe) is not directly launched (I don't do a double-click) but it's another application that starts this one. "Sub-process" is my own word, sorry, don't know the exact word.